# FCM token can't be accessed in Meteor React Application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, meteor, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging for notification in my Meteor application. I've followed [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) documentation(official FCM documentation for Node.js application) to integrate Firebase SDK into the Meteor project for client side. Then I've written a serviceworker file and put it in `/client` directory. My `/client/firebase-messaging-sw.js` file looks like bellow:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";

var config = {
  apiKey: "API-KEY",
  authDomain: "PROJECT.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://PROJECT.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "PROJECT.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "SENDER-ID"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

In `componentDidMount` of my react component I wrote following snippet:

```
componentDidMount(){
  const messaging = firebase.messaging();
  messaging.requestPermission()
  .then(function(){
      console.log("permission granted");
      return messaging.getToken();
  })
  .then(function(token){
      console.log(token);
  })
  .catch(function(error){
      console.log("error getting permission : " , error);
  })
}
```

When the application runs it gets the notification permission properly, but gets a reject value in the promise due to `messaging.getToken()` method.

Is there any problem in the process I followed to integrate FCM in my Meteor app? Or can anyone suggest any reference to integrate FCM in Meteor?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Didn't try it lately. May be the reason was insecure connection. FCM for Web requires HTTPS connection as per [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client)

Comment: Hello @Stephan I've just tried it, but didn't get any luck!  :(

Comment: still not working ?

Comment: Didn't check it lately. Last time I checked it didn't work for me.